# Multiple use of jquery-ui slider but with different min max values set by php programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i use jquery-ui and some range sliders, which are specified in an external JavaScript file like follows:

```
$( function() {
$( ".slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  values: [ 75, 300 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).prev().val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  }
});
$(".slider-range").on("slidestop", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).prev().val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    localStorage.setItem(this.getAttribute("id") + '_min', ui.values[ 0 ]);
    localStorage.setItem(this.getAttribute("id") + '_max', ui.values[ 1 ]);
    aktualisiert();
});
$('.slider-range').prev().val( $( ".slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  "-" + $( ".slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

the sliders are used in an PHP file like this:

```
<label>Price range:</label>
<input type="text" name="this_slider1" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">

<div id="this_slider1" class="slider-range"></div>
<br>


<label>Price range:</label>
<input type="text" name="this_slider2" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">

<div id="this_slider2" class="slider-range"></div>
<br>
```

My Problem is that, after submitting the form, which on "slidestop" of the range-slider within the aktualisiert() function is done, the values of the range slider are reset. So i need to set the values back to the values which were selected. For this i saved the values in the local storage and try to reset the values after the page with all the range sliders is refreshed. I try this like follows:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var range_sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-range");
    for (i = 0; i < range_sliders.length; i++) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min') != null){
            $('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  0, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min'));
            $('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  1, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_max'));
            $('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('refresh');
        }
    }
});
```

But it is not working. I checked with an alert box that the if statement is entered. But the values of the range slider are set at the default values. I also tried

```
$('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('option','values', [ localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min'), localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_max')]);
```

instead of

```
$('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  0, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min'));
$('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  1, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_max'));
```

but all of this is not working. Where do i have the mistake. I think the mistake is in these rows

```
$('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  0, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min'));
$('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  1, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_max'));
```

because if i add an alert before them and after them only the one before is shown. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var range_sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-range");
    for (i = 0; i < range_sliders.length; i++) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min') != null){
            try {
                $('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  0, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min'));
                $('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider('values',  1, localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_max'));
                $('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).prev().val( localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_min') + "-" + localStorage.getItem(range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id") + '_max') );
            }
            catch(err) {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I put the code to set the values like this and it worked so it was necssary to put it into the

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
});
```

section and to call the selector like

```
$('#' + range_sliders[i].getAttribute("id")).slider
```

That was all. Maybe it will help any other person in the future.